# Different type of inner joins and name of them

Tags: join, powerquery

I have two simple datasets:

Person dataset

```
ID Name Place

1 Person1 City1
2 Person2 City2
4 Person4 City3
```

Equipment dataset:

```
ID Equipment

1 Computer
1 Screen
2 Computer
3 Computer
```

Now I want to combine these datasets to get the following result:

```
ID Name Place Equipment

1 Person1 City1 Computer
1 Person1 City1 Screen
2 Person2 City2 Computer
```

This is an inner join, according to my knowledge.

**Type 1**

If I use PowerQuery in Excel to do the job (Select Inner Join):

[image: PQ]

I can see:

[image: e2]

When I add to display the information from the second table:

[image: ex2]

it looks like this:

[image: ex]

And the final result is as follows:

[image: example]

As I expected.

I would name this join an "Inner Join".

**Type 2**

Now I have a software where I can perform data manipulation and I use this and join the datasets with the option "Join only matches". From my point of view it should join the matches, so Person with ID 1 and 2 (and to be specific join the 2 rows from the second column for person, so both Computer and Screen). However, the result is as follows:

[image: op]

I was surprised and did not expect this. My two questions now are:

1.)

How are these joins called? I would call type 1 an "Inner Join", but I don't know how I would call type 2? Also "Inner Join"? Is there a specific type of different inner joins existing explaining this different behaviour? So like full inner join and strict inner join (as examples).

2.)

Isn't the result in the second example a bit misleading, "not professional"? I had a large dataset and did not get a warning nor did I see it immediately.

Comment: Where is your code, what have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Grumpy I have no "code". The results were created as I explained with PowerQuery and with another software. No actual code was written.

Comment: For the Power Query code, navigate to `Home => Advanced Editor`. Then copy/paste the code that you see into your question.

Comment: Does the software you're using for the Type 2 join have a setting for returning either first match or last match? If the software was designed primarily for ETL use, that type of setting could make sense in a "lookup" situation. It would also only return a single matching row for the second table, instead of all matching rows.

Comment: It does not have a setting for returning either first match or last match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an inner join with a group-by statement to preserve row count of the left table, where it has picked the first row of the matched table for retention.

Since this isn't a join but a join and a filter - it does not have a join name. But it is not a true inner join, on this we can all agree.

I'm not sure we can be judges in terms of how the software is "professional" or not, without knowing what the software is, what it does or how you have used it.

Answer (score 1):

> "Join only matches"

We do not know the tool, but the behaviour seems to be similar to  lookup operation. It takes table one as the driving table and tries to find a corresponding row/value in the second table.

There is similar operation in Microsoft SSIS: [Lookup Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/lookup-transformation?view=sql-server-ver15)

> **The Lookup transformation performs lookups by joining data in input columns with columns in a reference dataset. You use the lookup to access additional information in a related table that is based on values in common columns.**
>
> ...
>
> **The Lookup transformation tries to perform an equi-join between values in the transformation input and values in the reference dataset.** (An equi-join means that each row in the transformation input must match at least one row from the reference dataset.) If an equi-join is not possible, the Lookup transformation takes one of the following actions
>
> **If there is no matching entry in the reference dataset, no join occurs.** By default, the Lookup transformation treats rows without matching entries as errors. However, you can configure the Lookup transformation to redirect such rows to a no match output.
>
> **If there are multiple matches in the reference table, the Lookup transformation returns only the first match returned by the lookup query.**
>
> **If multiple matches are found, the Lookup transformation generates an error or warning only when the transformation has been configured to load all the reference dataset into the cache.** In this case, the Lookup transformation generates a warning when the transformation detects multiple matches as the transformation fills the cache.

---

SQL Server Equivalent is CROSS APPLY/LATERAL JOIN and correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person p
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Equipment e WHERE p.id = e.Id) sub;
-- please note the first row is random without explicit ORDER BY
```

[image]

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c574224aa48d909bc2710efd4e28a2ce)**

When used directly in `SELECT` list as correlated subquery it has the following properties:

1. subquery has to return single column with zero or one value
2. if more than one row is returned by the subquery, entire statement will error out
3. It will return all rows from main table, even without matches

Sample:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT  Equipment FROM Equipment e WHERE p.id = e.Id) AS Equipment
FROM Person p;
-- error

SELECT *, (SELECT TOP 1 Equipment FROM Equipment e WHERE p.id = e.Id) AS Equipment
FROM Person p;
```